# Show half of sentences instead of full sentences in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Now in repeater I wan to display a sentences in database but because the sentence length are too long and will affect the repeater size. May I know how to just know a part of the sentences instead of the full sentences?

Comment: It's probably good to know a bit of the standard library if you want to make an asp.net website... In this case, you can for example use [String.Substring](http://csharp.net-informations.com/string/csharp-string-substring.htm).

Comment: Thanks.. SubString are work :D

Answer (score 1):

Stick this peice of logic somewhere that you can call when rendering the value of sentence:

`YourSentence.Length < MaxSentenceLength ? YourSentence : YourSentence.Substring(0, MaxSentenceLength)`